# Django nested if else in templates

Tags: python, django

I'm using django embeded video so when user puts youtube link video I can have the thumbnail of the video using

```
<img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
```

but when user inserts the link that that's not an youtube video I want to insert default image.

currently this is what I have

```
{% if post.main_image %} //if post has main_image
<img src="{{post.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
  {% elif post.url %} //if post has url
    {% video post.video as my_video %} 
      {% if my_video %}//if that url is an link to video
        <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
        {% elif %} //if that url isn't a video
        <img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ EBAGU" height="75" width="75"/>
        {% endif %}
   {% endvideo %}
{% else %} //if it  doesn't have main_image or link
<img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
{% endif %}
```

with the above code I get

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /post/aa-2/
Unexpected end of expression in if tag.
```

at {% if my_video%}

can someone please help me

This is a link to embed video app-> http://django-embed-video.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1.0/examples.html#template-examples

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your `{% elif %}` in `{% if my video...%}` doesn't have any condition.

I think you should have  `{% else %}` instead?

```
{% if my_video %}//if that url is an link to video
    <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="" height="75" width="75"/>
{% else %} //if that url isn't a video
    <img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt=" EBAGU" height="75" width="75"/>
{% endif %}
```

Fixed version based on the dpaste in the comments:

```
<td>
    {% if post.main_image %}
        <img src="{{post.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
    {% elif post.url %}
      {% video post.url as my_video %}
          {% if my_video %}
              <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
          {% else %}
              <img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
          {% endif %}
      {% endvideo %}
        <img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
    {% endif %}
</td>
```

Comment: my bad I put elif because I have something above there...I'll post the full code

Comment: wait the above code is same as what I did no?I'll check

Comment: I have an {% else %} instead of {% elif %}

Comment: ah thank you but I remeber trying this but I got an error...this is my code for this http://dpaste.com/2R00BPT and I get Invalid block tag: 'endvideo', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'....and without {% endvideo %} I get expected endvideo which I don;t understand

Comment: You are not closing the video tag in the code you posted on dpaste

Comment: no I closed it, did you scroll right? you can see {%endvideo%} next to <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>

Comment: You need to close it outside of your if since you are declaring the video tag outside of your if...

Comment: hmm thank you but I get two images now, the default image when url isn't video and youtube thumbnail video

Comment: You are always writing out the ```<img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>```. Anyhow, that's a different problem, your original question is answered.

Comment: Ah-ha thanks I forgot to add else before the thumbnail...yes it did get answered thanks

Comment: actually problem isn't solved, when I enter url that's not video link I don't get any image which   {% else %}
<img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/> isn't working....any help please??

Comment: I have done it in very hackish way, even I know I shouldn't do it this way...would appreciate if you take a look at this for sec...http://dpaste.com/2VSVVN8

Comment: thanks man but I couldn't solve this I made a new post....with the above I'm unable to display post.image if the link isn't url...so the whole thing was wrong approach...I made a new post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552493/how-to-show-other-image-of-image-is-none