# how to show other image of image is none

Tags: python, django

after I've thought real hard I just don't know what's wrong with my code and how I can modify it.

The problem is this:when user inserts url and if that url is a link to youtube, then youtube thumbnail needs to be displayed. if that url isn't a link to youtube video, post.image(default image) needs to be displayed. But post.image is not getting displayed!

both images can be displayed if I choose to which means if/else statement is wrong

So this is my full code;
I'll comment through the below code, if anyone can please tell me what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate
video tags come from this third party app django-embeded-video.
http://django-embed-video.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1.0/examples.html#template-examples

```
<td>
  {% if post.main_image %} //if post has main_image
    <img src="{{post.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>//display that image
  {% elif post.url %}//if post has url
    {% video post.url as my_video %} //setting post.url as my_video(problem starts here I think)
      {% if my_video %} //if my_video is there
        <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/> //display the video thumbnail
      {% else %} //if my_video isn't there and post.url isn't a link to youtube
        <img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ " height="75" width="75"/> //display post.image
      {% endif %}
    {% endvideo %}
  {% else %} 
    <img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
  {% endif %}
</td>
```

what am I doing wrong

Edit: Found a problem I think but not sure how to fix it
When I do 
        {% video post.url as my_video %} I'm setting post.url to my_video and when I do if statement on this it would say yes it exists no matter url is youtube link or not...now one step down...

Comment: Have you tried taking out the {% video block and just putting in "hello world" to see if it is the condition that is the problem or the video template tag?

Comment: @PhoebeB I found the problem....please see the edit

Comment: How about doing the test for the url being youtube outside the {% video section.  ie. {% if "youtube" in post.url %}