# if/else using javascript...doing very hackish way to solve the issue I've been having

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I probably shouldn't do it this way but I need to borrow power of javascript. so in my web users can post links, and if that link is youtube the video thumbnail can be displayed. if it's some site other than youtube some other image, named post.image can be displayed. Problem is, I can't do if and else(in django template language) for this. I tried multiple times but failed. Here's my last attempt [how to show other image of image is none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552493/how-to-show-other-image-of-image-is-none)

```
<td>
  {% if post.main_image %} //if post has main_image
    <img src="{{post.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>//display that image
  {% elif post.url %}//if post has url
    {% video post.url as my_video %} //setting post.url as my_video(problem starts here I think)
      {% if my_video %} //if my_video is there
        <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/> //display the video thumbnail
      {% else %} //if my_video isn't there and post.url isn't a link to youtube
        <img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ " height="75" width="75"/> //display post.image
      {% endif %}
    {% endvideo %}
  {% else %} 
    <img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
  {% endif %}
</td>
```

so main thing to look at it is
for post.url if I don't have     `<img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>` 
I want

```
<img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ " height="75" width="75"/> //display post.image
```

Now I realize this can might be done with javascript, but I'm not an expert at javascript...can someone please give me some advice if I can do this with js?

Comment: Why not added a property to your model that check if the url the user is submitting is from Youtube or not. Then you won't have that logic in you templates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show other image of image is none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552493/how-to-show-other-image-of-image-is-none)