# Django nested if statement giving me a strange error

Tags: django, if-statement

I have 2 if statements right next to each other to check for to see if a user is following another user. I am getting a weird error when I attempt to close both of the if statements. I have a block content and endblock at the top and bottom of the page. I also have a load humanize tag. I have attempted to add a endblock tag and I tried reshuffling things around. I am kinda stuck but I know I'm forgetting something. Can any help me out?

Here is the code

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %} {% load humanize %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-12">
      <h1 class="title">{{ request.user.username }}</h1>
      <p>Followers: {{ user.foxyprofile.followed_by.count }}</p>
      <p>Follows {{ user.foxyprofile.follows.count }}</p>
      {% if user != request.user %} {% if request.user.foxyprofile in
      user.foxyprofile.followed_by.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'unfollow_foxy' user.username %}" class="button is-danger"
        >Unfollow</a
      >
      {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'follow_foxy' user.username %}" class="button is-success"
        >Follow {{ user.username}}</a
      >
      {% endif %} {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-8">
      <div class="wrapper-fox">
        {% for fox in user.foxs.all %}
        <div class="fox">
          <p class="name">{{ fox.created_by.username }}</p>
          <p>{{ fox.body }}</p>
          <p class="info">{{ fox.created_at|naturaltime}}</p>
          <hr />
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and the error I'm getting...

Invalid block tag on line 17: 'endif', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: also show the part of the code where you have started and ended the block.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha I added the whole bit!

Comment: `user` is normally always `request.user` *unless* `user` is specified in the context. But we can not see that part.

Comment: user is specified in my views.

Comment: You can find your answer here
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528958/django-nested-if-else-in-templates/36529093>

Comment: @AaronCloud: you should not add a line break in the second `if` statement, a tag is fully specified on a *single* line.

Comment: @ShubhVaishnav I did see that, and i tried it and no same error. Thank you tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add a line break in the second `if` statement, a tag is fully specified on a *single* line. This thus means that the [**`{% if … %}`** tags [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if) look like:

```
{% if user != request.user %}
    {% if request.user.foxyprofile in user.foxyprofile.followed_by.all %}
        …
    {% else %}
        …
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

or you put the two `{% if … %}` tags on the same line:

```
{% if user != request.user %}{% if request.user.foxyprofile in user.foxyprofile.followed_by.all %}
        …
{% else %}
        …
{% endif %}{% endif %}
```

You can also write the `{% if … %}`s on two lines and the two `{% endif %}` on the same line. The only thing that is not allowed is splitting a tag over multiple lines in the template file.

In Django the *template parser* can not handle template tags on multiple lines, or at least not at the time of writing.

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem, I believe that was it. It is working now! How strange but it makes sense that it would be line sensitive like that.

Comment: @AaronCloud: well, I'm not verry happy with Django's template engine. It has a certain amount of *peculiarities*, like spaces before/after a pipe charcter (`|`) for a template filter, and I think it has no "formal" specifications what it should do when parsing a space/new line. I agree that this is indeed one of the less nicely implemented things.

Comment: "The only thing that is not allowed is splitting a tag over multiple lines in the template file.", interesting... jus tested with `{% else %}{% endif %}` in the same line to see if it'd pick up... but no. Always learning...